# Implementing dummy to windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnet-cli

i'm in a project trying to find the best way to implement an interactive dummy to a windows form software. I think the tools on visual studio aren't good enough to do so. 
Any suggestions of softwares that i can use to implement this?

tks